# How to run a X11 program from another TTY

Tags: linux, xorg, tty

My X desktop environment is on TTY2, and I want to run an X program on TTY3 so that it opens within the X graphical desktop of TTY2.

Before executing the program, I added the display variable using this:

```
export DISPLAY=:0
```

But I have the follow error:

```
qt.qpa.screen: QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display :0.0
Could not connect to any X display.
```

So, how can I fix this error and run the program in the X server into TTY2?